# Traefik block external access for hostname

Tags: docker, ssl, https, firewall, traefik

I have two docker containers that need to share the HTTPS port, each with a different hostname. A Traefik container with letsencrypt seems like a good option, but here's the tricky bit: one of the containers should only allow internal access.

With HTTP sites, I could just block external access to the hostname on my router, but because of SSL I don't have that information until after decryption, i.e. somewhere in or after the Traefik container. Is there some way to achieve this, or am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: what do you mean with `router`? Are you talking about a network router?

Comment: Exactly. With HTTP it would be simple to block access where my network connects to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I never did find out if Traefik could do what I wanted, but ended up solving it differently. Since one domain was only going to be accessed internally, I left that at port 443. The other domain got a different port on the server, but I had my router point 443 to that port. So if I want to access the external site internally, I need to go via the external IP/domain but that works fine.